# Trying to calculate the difference between 2 time and dates using moment.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, momentjs

I'm using a date/time picker that I found on https://material-ui-pickers.dev/ and wanted to use it with the moment.js library. I'm having some issues. I have a form that collects a start time and an end time. I wanted to use the moment.js "diff" method to calculate the difference in hours. I keep getting "20.4234254" or similar, regardless of what dates & times I enter.

The format of the date as it's being held in state and managed by moment.js is:
"Wed Jul 08 2020 21:51:23 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)".

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
import {
  DatePicker,
  TimePicker,
  DateTimePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';
import moment from 'moment';



function DateFormField() {
  const [startDate, startTime] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, endTime] = useState(new Date());
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState("");
  
  const timeCalc = (startDate, endDate) => {
    var start = moment(startDate);
    var end = moment(endDate);
    console.log(end.diff(start, "hours", true) + ' hours');
  }


  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
        
      <DateTimePicker value={startDate} onChange={startTime} helperText="Start Time" />
      <DateTimePicker value={endDate} onChange={endTime} helperText="End Time" />
      <button onClick={timeCalc}>Time Duration: {duration}</button>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default DateFormField;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

I can't get this code to run in a sandbox (interacting with the `DateTimePicker` for some reason throws a `utils.getYearText is not a function` TypeError), but I think I know what the issue is.

You define `timeCalc` to consume two arguments, `startDate` and `endDate`

```
const timeCalc = (startDate, endDate) => {
  var start = moment(startDate);
  var end = moment(endDate);
  console.log(end.diff(start, "hours", true) + ' hours');
}
```

but in the button to trigger it you simply attach the function to the `onClick` handler, so it is *actually* only passed the event object as the first argument and undefined for the second.

```
<button onClick={timeCalc}>Time Duration: {duration}</button>
```

I then tested `timeCalc` manually in the function body by passing it the `startDate` and `endDate` state values and it (presumably) correctly returns `0 hours`, as would be expected from two *nearly* identical timestamps.

```js
const timeCalc = (startDate, endDate) => {
  var start = moment(startDate);
  var end = moment(endDate);
  console.log(end.diff(start, "hours", true) + " hours");
};

timeCalc(new Date(), new Date());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

## Solution

Either remove the arguments to `timeCalc` so the referenced `startDate` and `endDate` values will be the ones in global component scope

```
const timeCalc = () => {
  var start = moment(startDate);
  var end = moment(endDate);
  console.log(end.diff(start, "hours", true) + ' hours');
}
```

Or explicitly pass the state values to the callback

```
<button onClick={() => timeCalc(startDate, endDate)}>
  Time Duration: {duration}
</button>
```